# Is there a way to see how much memory a variable uses?

Tags: perl, memory-management

I am working with Perl for some months now.
As for now, my scripts work but they are far from being perfect.

I would now like to optimize the memory usage, thus I am looking for a way to break down the memory usage per variable/hash.

Is there a way to see how much memory a variable uses?

Comment: Be careful about _optimizing_. 99% of the time, developers simply optimize against the wrong things. You watch your variable usage, save a few hundred bytes, then do a `foreach` loop and end up eating massive amounts of memory because a `foreach` loop requires the entire array to be loaded before running. And, you can introduce errors. I saw someone push to array references into two separate variables, then was shocked that modifying one variable modified the other. Use Devel::Size, but optimize your code readability before memory. Memory is cheap. Developer time figuring out your code isn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Devel::Size](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aSize) or [Devel::Size::Report](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aSize%3a%3aReport) can be used to get memory usage for a variable/structure.

You might want to check [perl guts illustrated](http://search.cpan.org/dist/illguts/index-14.html) to see what the numbers really mean.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Devel::Size](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aSize) on CPAN.